# shutil.move can't move files between disk drives?

Tags: python, shutil

I am using shutil.move to move files from my downloads (C:) to a folder on a server (Z:).

```
source_dir = "C:\\Users\\e1206433\\Downloads\\estadisticaEjecGlo*.csv"
dest_dir1 = "Z:\\AN\Produban\Operations\Print Management\Misc\Luca\TEST 1"

for file in glob.glob(source_dir):
    print(file)
    shutil.move(file, dest_dir1)
```

But, for some reason everytime the script is run it returns this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk drive: 'C:\\Users\\e1206433\\Downloads\\EstadisticaEjecGlo095914.csv' -> 'Z:\\AN\\Produban\\Operations\\Print Management\\Misc\\Luca\\TEST 1'
```

My understanding is that this error is presented when using os.rename, and that shutil.move is the solution. But my script is already using shutil!

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try using `copy2` instead of `move`?

Comment: have you tried using `os.system()` or `suprocess.run()` instead?

Comment: which python version?

Comment: @ddor254 Python 3.7 is the version Im using

Comment: @Aran-Fey copy2 seems to present a new error, even though the directory exists: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Z:\\AN\\Produban\\Operations\\Print Management\\Misc\\Luca\\TEST 1'

Comment: So if you create that directory, does the code work then?

Comment: The directory already exists :( and it still doesn't work @Aran-Fey

Comment: Oh. Then I guess `Z:\` is a network drive, right? Python can't natively access network drives.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Yeah that's right, the Z: is a network drive, but I have mapped it onto the computer? How can I make Python access the network drive? Thank you

Comment: No idea, sorry. I'd have to google that, just like you.

Comment: I have the same trouble with normal (non network) drive and python 3.6.5